# pip3 packages are getting installed in /home/user/.local/python3.8/site-packages/ but not able to use them at all

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, as and when I install any package using

```
pip3 install any_python_pacakage
```

Everything gets installed and no problem occurs.

But when I try to use to any package using:

```
from any_package_name import any_name
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'build' from 'googleapiclient.discovery' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py)
```

Please help, because I cannot use any package installed using `pip3`.

Any help needed from my side, I am ready.

And also in my `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/any_pkg`, all the modules using `pip3` are installed with 0but when I check deeply there, every file there installed is of zero size.

[image: files with size 0]

And somebody on ask ubuntu told me to force reinstall the packages that I am messing up, with this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall <pkg_name>
```

But this has worsened the scenario.

Now I cannot use `pip3` at all to install anything and the error is:

[image: new_error]